# Maya MFnRotateManip view rotation handle

Tags: c++, plugins, maya

The view rotation ring (the outer one) of the MFnRotateManip doesn't seem to be working correctly. Even in the [rotateManip example](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/rotate_manip_8cpp-example.html), it only produces correct rotations if the initial rotation of the object is 0,0,0. Otherwise the rotation axis is not aligned with the view axis. What am I missing?

Using Maya 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, and it still doesn't work in Maya 2013. The MFnRotateManip only works correctly with setRotateMode(MFnRotateManip::kWorldSpace) and setInitialRotation(MEulerRotation()).

If anyone from Autodesk reads this: The fix would be pretty easy, just transform the delta rotation from the outer rotation ring into the object coordinate system before applying it to the output values and the inner rings.